# join 2 data sets and compare in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

Can someone please help with the following using python code?

- I have 2 csv data sets each with a million records
- Both files have the same column names and total of 200 (100 in each)
- the 2 files are month over month transactions. So, many records may overlap, however, some columns can have change in value
- There will be some records that are unique to File A and/or B

File A

```
ID,      items,      Amount

A1,       10,         100

A2,       20,         200

A3,       30,         300
```

File B

```
ID,      items,      Amount

A1,       10,         100

A2,       12,         120

A4,       40,         400
```

I need the final output to be as follows

```
FileA-ID,  FileB-ID,  Match?, FileA-Items, FileB-items,  Match?,  FileA-Amount, FileB-Amount, Match?

A1,          A1,        Y,      10,            10,         Y,         100,         100,         Y,
A2,          A2,        Y,      20,            12,         N,         100,         120,         N,
A3,          NAN,       N,      30,           NAN,         N,         300,         NAN,         N,
NAN,         A4,        N,      NAN,           40,         N,         NAN,         400,         N
```

This will be a monthly process, so i want to make the code generic so i can just rerun every month on a new file.

Answer (score 0):

First you can keep track of your original columns into a list.

```py
cols = df1.columns.tolist()
```

Then set `ID` column as index, and properly rename your two dataframe's column headers. Concat the two dataframes along columns.

```py
df1 = df1.set_index('ID')
df2 = df2.set_index('ID')
df1['ID'] = df1.index
df2['ID'] = df2.index

df1 = df1.rename(lambda col: f'FileA-{col}', axis=1)
df2 = df2.rename(lambda col: f'FileB-{col}', axis=1)

df_ = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

```
print(df_)

    FileA-items  FileA-Amount FileA-ID  FileB-items  FileB-Amount FileB-ID
ID                                                                        
A1         10.0         100.0       A1         10.0         100.0       A1
A2         20.0         200.0       A2         12.0         120.0       A2
A3         30.0         300.0       A3          NaN           NaN      NaN
A4          NaN           NaN      NaN         40.0         400.0       A4
```

At last, create `Match` column according to the same column in df1 and df2. Then sort the columns header.

```py
for col in cols:
    df_[f'Match-{col}'] = np.where((df_[f'FileA-{col}'] == df_[f'FileB-{col}']), 'Y', 'N')

df_ = df_.reindex(sorted(df_.columns, key = lambda x: cols.index(x.split('-')[1])), axis=1)
```

```
print(df_)

   FileA-ID FileB-ID Match-ID  FileA-items  FileB-items Match-items  FileA-Amount  FileB-Amount Match-Amount
ID                                                                                                          
A1       A1       A1        Y         10.0         10.0           Y         100.0         100.0            Y
A2       A2       A2        Y         20.0         12.0           N         200.0         120.0            N
A3       A3      NaN        N         30.0          NaN           N         300.0           NaN            N
A4      NaN       A4        N          NaN         40.0           N           NaN         400.0            N


print(df_.reset_index(drop=True))

  FileA-ID FileB-ID Match-ID  FileA-items  FileB-items Match-items  FileA-Amount  FileB-Amount Match-Amount
0       A1       A1        Y         10.0         10.0           Y         100.0         100.0            Y
1       A2       A2        Y         20.0         12.0           N         200.0         120.0            N
2       A3      NaN        N         30.0          NaN           N         300.0           NaN            N
3      NaN       A4        N          NaN         40.0           N           NaN         400.0            N
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for this! Getting the following error when I try to concat: Shape of passed values is (806869, 218), indices imply (797848, 218). On reading online, it talks about how we should delete some duplicate rows, but i want to keep all rows intact. I tried the outer join, df_= df1.join(df, how='outer') - but not sure if this will result in loss of data somewhow

Comment: @rvs Are your `ID` column in `df1` and `ID` column in `df2` both unique?

Comment: unfortunately, there are overlaps. however, i need to retain both since i need to show if the values between these two files is consistent month over month

Comment: hi, i figured it out. Thank you so much for help!